# Add a landscape page to a pivot view

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, pivotviewer

I'm trying to add one landscape page to my pivot view.
The rest of the pages are portrait pages.

How can I achieve this?

This is a sample of what I want

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="BitcoinTicker.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <phone:Pivot Title="App title">

            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="First">
                <!-- Portrait page -->
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Second">
                <!-- Landscape page -->
            </phone:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item three -->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Third">
                <!-- Portrait page -->
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>

    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Cheers

Comment: If you are trying to mimic the Pictures app you should use a Panorama, not a Pivot. PanoramaItem has an [Orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.panoramaitem.orientation(v=vs.105).aspx) property that supports "wide" content

Comment: No I just want to display one graph item in a landscape way instead of  a portrait.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a panorama and follow certain Windows Phone Design Guidelines. Details explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202912(v=vs.105).aspx